# SKShapeNode as touch responder, SKSpriteNode as drawing

Tags: sprite-kit, touch, skspritenode, skshapenode

Because SKSpriteNode doesn't differentiate alpha content from opaque content, it's not accurate for receiving touches of a complex shape (non rectangular). Is it possible to use an SKShapeNode as the touch responder, and an SKSpriteNode as the drawing component, so as to get the best of both worlds?

Comment: SKShapeNode is in the same boat,  it checks touch via a square based on the frame property.  Remember, chances are you are working with fingers here, so having pixel perfect accuracy may not be a well thought out design for your app. What are you trying to do here and perhaps we can come up with a way to effectively create the behavior you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Are your shapes totally arbitrary? I've noticed you've discussed using `SKShapeNode`s a lot. Could you give some examples that you are trying to build? It may be easier to understand what you are trying to do and get alternatives. `SKShapeNode`s could be more trouble than they are worth ... depending.

Comment: A lot of the objects are big circles, or rectangles with heavily rounded corners. And I don't want touches in the corners (outside the shapes) to respond as if they're touching inside the shape, when they're clearly not. I've (for now) given up on the sexy rounded rectangles and resorted to a circle radius check to make the touch "accurate". @MobileBen

Comment: @Knight0fDragon for a while I was considering placing a "touch object" that's a physics body wherever the finger touches, and then checking a physics body contact with the target object, to see if there is contact. This way I can have complex shapes with accurate touch. For now, I'm settling with the radius check, but I feel I'm going to have to figure out how to do the physics way to handle the more complex shapes.

Comment: And @Knight0fDragon you're right, I've also discovered SKShapeNodes do a rectangular touch check, too. Nothing to do with their actual content. Very annoying.

Comment: if you want accuracy. you can use the path you would have used for a shape node, and check the point with `CGPathContainsPoint`, you of course need to make sure that the path is where your sprite is, or translate the touch point from scene coordinate to sprite coordinate

Comment: If this is for touch events and provided your objects are reasonable in terms of geometric terms and your numbers are reasonable, you can always use compound objects instead of an `SKShapeNode`. Essentially your "parent" will have all the parts you'd be adding onto the `SKShapeNode` as it's children. Then for collision, you first check the parent frame, then go through each child for more precise testing. At this point, your child should have some attribute as to shape type.

Comment: @MobileBen if you imagine a sausage shaped button, circles at either end and a rectangle in the middle joining them, could this work for your description of compound objects?

Comment: Yes, doable. You could use 3 nodes. A rect and 2 circles. There obviously is overlap. Checking is trivial since it is radial or bounding box. Alternatively, it would not be unheard of to have a texture shaped like that. You can still do testing that would account for the construction. Keep in mind that depending on the size and if this is for touch, there is some forgiveness. People have fat fingers. I have bullet buttons and I use a simple quad test. I haven't had complaints.